# JWT Logout "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, postman, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am trying to create a Logout endpoint for a jwt token in djangorestframework. When I access this endpoint via postman, I get `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`
What am I missing here?

1. Am I supposed to create a serializer that has a field for the refresh token and add it to the view?
2. Am I parsing the data corretly in postman?

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            refresh_token = request.data["refresh_token"]
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
from accounts.views.user_api_views import (
    LogoutView,
    LogoutAllView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path("auth/", include("djoser.urls")),
    path("auth/", include("djoser.urls.jwt")),
    path("auth/token/", ObtainCustomizedTokenView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
    path(
        "auth/token/refresh/",
        jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(),
        name="token_refresh",
    ),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("logout_all/", LogoutAllView.as_view(), name="logout_all"),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # local apps
    # 3rd party
    "storages",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_gis",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "djoser",
    "django_celery_beat",
    "raven.contrib.django.raven_compat",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist",
]

......
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(weeks=521),  # 10 years
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(weeks=521),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": None,
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("JWT",),
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
}

......
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.FormParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"),
}
```

**Image from Postman**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the setting `"AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("JWT",)` from SIMPLE_JWT settings. My settings modified settings file is as follows:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(weeks=521),  # 10 years
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(weeks=521),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": None,
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
}
```

Alternatively, adding Bearer to the list of `"AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("JWT","Bearer")` also worked. When choosing the authorization type in postman, It gives you the option of `Bearer Token`. This means that, the view will look for a header containing the pattern `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.